# Assign Array of Dates to ngx-mydatepicker disableDates

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the ngx-mydatepicker in my project and I need to use the `disableDates` option which is an array of the `ngx-mydatepicker` custom interface `IMyDate`.  The dates I have are an array of `Date`.

**Example: See app.component.ts**

[Stackblitz Editor Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wj1kfd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**TS**

```
  //normally this comes from an API call.  They need to get
  //assigned to the disableDates below.
  invalidJsDates: Date[] = [new Date("2018-05-09"), new Date("2018-05-29")];

  myOptions: INgxMyDpOptions = {
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      //disableDates: this.invalidJsDates //need to convert this to array of IMyDate
  };
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" style="float:none" placeholder="Select a date" ngx-mydatepicker name="mydate"
              [(ngModel)]="model" [options]="myOptions" #dp="ngx-mydatepicker"/>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dp.clearDate()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Clear
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="dp.toggleCalendar()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>Toggle
          </button>
      </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: You will need to convert your date objects into the `IMyDate` type. You can run a `map` operation on those dates to get the year, month, and day that the interface requires. https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker/blob/922441e88a68cb284353d8fe55e2e69e37e806cc/src/ngx-my-date-picker/interfaces/my-date.interface.ts#L1-L5 If you aren't sure how to use the dates to get this data, here is the API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks!  That pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It was the weird syntax of "creating an instance of an interface" that was throwing me (coming from a C# background), as well as the `getMonth() + 1` that gets me every time I work with Dates in JS.

I still feel like this is harder than it needs to be, and there's probably a more "Angular" way to do it, but this works and I can finally move on.

I finally got it working after Daniel's comment:

```
  //an array of dates
  invalidDates: Date[] = [new Date("2018-05-09"), new Date("2018-05-29")];

  //mapped to an array of IMyDate
  datesForDisabled = this.invalidDates.map(d => <IMyDate>{ day: d.getDate(), month: d.getMonth() + 1, year: d.getFullYear()});

  //assigned to date picker
  myOptions: INgxMyDpOptions = {
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      disableDates: this.datesForDisabled
  };
```